# Retrieving words and scores of words associated with a topic in LDA sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lda, topic-modeling

I'm implementing topic modelling for the first time, and have gone with sklearn, rather than genism. The model has successfully implemented, but I would just love to get some more insights from the model on the words and the words score associated with each topic. I was wondering how I would get this as an output?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('topicDataSample.csv')
df_reduced_list = df_reduced["text"].values.tolist()
```

The `df_reduced_list` here is a list of the entries in one column of the dataframe. A sample is given below:

> ['More than satisfied with everything . They go beyond and more, I do not know where I would be without them.', 'It is hard to expect greatness from the team as they often go above expectations!  There are problems on occasion but admin staff is easy to talk to and they provide immediate rectification of issues.  Very happy with them!!!']

The sample above is obviously two list entries, but is just to provide an idea of what the data looks like.

```
import nltk
#nltk.download()
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer  
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')

bow_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words= list(stopwords), lowercase=True, max_df=0.5, 
min_df=10)
bow_matrix = bow_vectorizer.fit_transform(df_reduced_list)

from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation as LDA
lda_bow  = LDA(n_components=5, random_state=42) 
lda_bow.fit(bow_matrix)
lda_bow.transform(bow_matrix[:2])
```

I have then gone on to check the top words from the model, using this:

```
for idx, topic in enumerate(lda_bow.components_):
print(f"Top 5 words in Topic #{idx}:")
print([bow_vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()[i] for i in topic.argsort()[-5:]]) 
print('')
```

The sort of topics I get are as follows:

> Top 5 words in Topic #3:
> ['good', 'well', 'always', 'staff', 'care']

> Top 5 words in Topic #4:
> ['hospital', 'could', 'ward', 'would', 'told']

I have also visualised this in pyLDAviz, and have seen the distribution of topics.

What I am however trying to get is the word, the word score from the matrix, as well as the associated topic.

I've tried the answer provided here: [python scikit learn, get documents per topic in LDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45145368/python-scikit-learn-get-documents-per-topic-in-lda) but the result is not really what I would want:

> doc: 0 topic: 4

> doc: 1 topic: 3

> doc: 2 topic: 0

> doc: 3 topic: 3

> doc: 4 topic: 0

Also, I would love to see if I could get the text from the particular document printed out? So for instance, if I could have for example:

> doc: 4 **(the text of document 4 here)** topic: 0

All I'm getting is the entry from the matrix when I try to print. For example:
`[0.05779634, 0.05656708, 0.05656729, 0.05785048, 0.7712188]`

Any help to point me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.